# How to boot into Ubuntu 13 via Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, partitioning, multi-boot

My Disk Manager:

[image]

1. I installed XP on the first partition. (Drive D)
2. I installed Windows 7 (64 bit) on the second partition. (Drive C)
3. I installed EasyBCD 2.2 on the Windows 7

At this point my daul boot between XP and Windows 7 is just fine.

I then installed Ubuntu 13 (64 bit) on the 4th partition (78.13GB), I formatted the partition using Ubuntu Installer (ext4, with swap of 6GB), the installation was successful (I think)

After the installation of Ubuntu, there is no change to my the boot
screen, I have no way to boot into Ubuntu, so I tried to edit using
EasyBCD again.

...
I tried to follow the EasyBCD documentation.

I now can see the boot menu for booting into Ubuntu but after choosing it, I got this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to reinstall the grub from a ubuntu [liveCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD):

(i) boot to a live ubuntu, (ii) open a terminal (iii) type the following command:

```
sudo fdisk -l
sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt #where X is your ubuntu ext4 /(read root) partition
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

after these steps if no error accoured you can reboot and everything should be fine. at least you should be able to log into your ubuntu. and if you are not seeing other OSes in grub menu type the following command in ubuntu (from your installed one. not in live mode)

```
sudo update-grub
```

This should solved your problem unless you have a `UEFI` problem. If you have one you may need more steps.

By the way for Ubuntu specific question you can use [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: Please explain what is Live Ubuntu?, Now what I have is USB Ubuntu installation, is this what you meant??? Sorry I'm new for Ubuntu.

Comment: @Kongthap I updated my post and added liveCD link. please read that link. you probably have one (the one you installed from) or you need to make one. make `unetbootin` to make a usb bootable liveCD.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, you just helped me solve my problem.

Comment: @Kongthap :) glad I could help. God bless you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a recovery disk and then install windows first.Then make a fresh installation of linux in the unallocated space(by shrinking any of your partition through control panel).